# Is it possible to enable php_ldap in an Azure WebRole?

Tags: php, azure

I have followed the instructions here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/#CustomizePHP for adding an extension but can not get the web role to recognize the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to load other extensions? There was a bug in the past, see this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/cd547ad3-c892-4ba4-82f4-c83690d18966/problem-with-loading-php-extensions

Also note that in order to load the php_ldap extension, it requires the following files: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll

Comment: Yes I am able to load the SQL extension (php_sqlsrv_53_ts). I tried unsuccessfully to update the path to include ibeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. I suppose I could try copying them to the windows directory (what I have seen in other non-azure threads)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not coming back to you earlier. How are you getting along?

Since I never used a PHP based Cloud Service I did some testing for you. I followed the link you mentioned in your post with one exception: I did **not** add the php_ldap.dll to my Cloud Service.

After deploying the Cloud Service I verified a statement I remember about newer PHP installers for Windows:

- They come with the required .dll files, like these for LDAP
- They add the PHP folder containing the .dll files to your path variable

And this was indeed true. All required files are available and in the correct location.

This is the result I get when verifying LDAP from PHPInfo:

[image]

All seems to be ok. Can you try this and let me know how it goes.